# Extract which condition within if() statement was met in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Is it possible to extract which statement within `if()` was met in R *keeping multiple conditions within the same `if()` statement*?

**Example:**

```r
cond1 <- TRUE
cond2 <- FALSE

if(cond1 & cond2){
  message("Both cond1 and cond2 are true!")
} else {
  # PRINT WHICH CONDITION WAS NOT MET FIRST
   message(some_code_here, "WAS NOT MET :(")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the individual conditions in-line:

```r
if ((c1 <- cond1) && (c2 <- cond2)){
  message("Both cond1 and cond2 are true!")
} else {
  # PRINT WHICH CONDITION WAS NOT MET FIRST
  if (!c1) message("condition 1")
  if (!c2) message("condition 2")
}
```

BTW: don't try using `&` within `if`: it'll work, but it *suggests* that you can do vectorized comparisons within the `if` condition, but you cannot. Instead, use `&&` within `if` or migrate to `ifelse` for vectorized conditionals.

In this answer, I'm assuming that `cond1` and `cond2` are really just placeholders for more-complex expressions that return `logical(1)`, and you choose to not re-execute them. I don't use the above technique, I lean towards an alternative that I think is a little more readable:

```r
c1 <- cond1
c2 <- cond2
if (c1 && c2){
  message("Both cond1 and cond2 are true!")
} else {
  # PRINT WHICH CONDITION WAS NOT MET FIRST
  if (!c1) message("condition 1")
  if (!c2) message("condition 2")
}
```

But perhaps to answer your literal question: after a complex combination of logicals is combined with `&&` and/or `||`, they cannot be "un-combined". The `&&`/`||` functions are really just inline binary functions that take the preceding expression and the following expression and do something with them. Imagine being able to take `x <- 1 + 2` (since `+` is also an inline binary function) and deduce from `x` (which is now merely "3" internally) the components used to sum into it. The only time a function output can have it input components deduced or extracted is when it explicitly includes it, perhaps as an `attr`ibute or in a `list`. For instance, if you look at the contents of `lm(mpg~disp, data=mtcars)`, you'll notice a `$call` property that in this case contains the arguments and data used in the original call. This is the exception for most in R, I believe.